# Create Macro to Find Text String Within a Range and Return Data From Matched Rows

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning, I am building a macro that will find a certain text from cell A2 sheet named Committees withing the range of P2:CP5000 in sheet called database, and return data of column A:O in the same rows from all the rows that contain this text string, and print it out started from cell F2 on the sheet called reports. Here is what I have done based on some suggestions. However, it is not returning expected values, it copies data from column A in Database to F:T in reports. Also I think the loop is not working since it won't stop after the last row in range r1.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
Dim rw1 As Long
Dim tmpRow As Long

tmpRow = 2
Set r2 = Sheets("Committees").Range("A2")
Set r1 = Sheets("Database").Range("P2:CO5000")
Set r3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reports").Range("F2:T2")

rw1 = 0
rw1 = r1.Find(What:=r2.Value, After:=r1(1)).Row

Do While rw1 <> 0
r3.Value = Sheets("Database").Range("A" & rw1 & ":O" & rw1).Value
tmpRow = tmpRow + 1
Set r3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reports").Range("F" & tmpRow & ":T" & tmpRow)
rw1 = 0
rw1 = r1.FindNext().Row
Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final Edit:**

I forgot to check for whether that particular cell had already been found (now with FirstAddress). The infinite loop was due to the code finding the same entries over and over.

I tested the following code, and it works for me.

```
Sub joseph()

Dim awb As Workbook
Dim cm, db, rp As Worksheet 'committees, database, reports

Dim tmpRng As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim tmpRow As Integer

Dim r As Integer

Dim searchValue As String


    Set awb = ThisWorkbook

    With awb
        Set cm = .Worksheets("Committees")
        Set db = .Worksheets("Database")
        Set rp = .Worksheets("Reports")
    End With

    searchValue = cm.Range("A2").Value

    tmpRow = 0
    r = 2

    With db

        Set tmpRng = .Range("P2:CP5000").Find(searchValue, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not tmpRng Is Nothing Then

            firstAddress = tmpRng.Address

            Do
                tmpRow = tmpRng.Row
                rp.Range("F" & r & ":T" & r).Value = .Range("A" & tmpRow & ":O" & tmpRow).Value
                r = r + 1
                Set tmpRng = .Range("P2:CP5000").FindNext(tmpRng)
            Loop While Not tmpRng Is Nothing And tmpRng.Address <> firstAddress

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

---

**Initial replies and edits:**

Try changing this line

```
Set rw1 = .FindNext(rw1)
```

to

```
rw1 = r1.FindNext().Row
```

rw1 is not a Range, therefore type mismatch. Let me know if this works.

**Edit**: also change this line:

```
If Not rw1 Is Nothing Then
```

to

```
if rw1 <> 0 then
```

and add this line

```
rw1 = 0
```

before this line:

```
rw1 = r1.Find(What:=r2.Value, After:=r1(1)).Row
```

**Edit2:** about the for loop and updating r3
If the text string exists multiple times, you must keep the for-loop, and you can update the r3 range by declaring a row variable, e.g.

```
Dim tmpRow = 2 as integer
```

and then inside your for-loop you write before `rw1 = 0`

```
tmpRow = tmpRow + 1
set r3 = thisWorkbook.Sheets("Reports").Range("F" & tmprow & ":T" & tmprow)
```

Comment: It is still saying rw1 is a mismatch

Comment: Thank you for responding me so quick. now it is saying the LastRow = Cells Sentence is a type mismatch now.

Comment: What is it supposed to be the lastrow of? Sheet Database? Also, what is Count?

Comment: Yes, it supposed to read until the last row of database within column P to CO, I realized the contradiction of r2 and lastRow there. The Count is just something I copy from the Internet, I am very new to VBA.

Comment: I guess in your case you can just have `lastrow = 5000` then, and also delete the row `Loop`

Comment: Thanks, it is now running, but it seems like it takes a long time.

Comment: Well, I would think that this is mostly due to the fact that you use the .copy method. It would be better to use something like `Workbook1.Worksheets("ABC").Range("A1:A10").Value = Workbook2.Worksheets("DEF").Range("A3:A13").Value`. This directly sets the values instead of first copying then pasting the data. If that does not speed it up, try adding `rw1 = 0` before this row: `rw1 = r1.FindNext().Row`, but this one is just a guess. I can't really test it now.

Comment: I have change the copy sentence to value, however, it is still very slow, I updated the code up there. Can you check if there is anyway to optimize the architecture?

Comment: first, you need to switch it around to `r3.Value = sheets("database")......` because you want to write into r3. What I do not get is, why do you loop through all rows in Database, but do not update your r3-Range? the text you are looking for, does it only exist once in database? If so, you don't need the for-loop. another thing, you should define r3 as range("F2:T2")

Comment: The text string that I am looking for only exist within the range of P:CO in sheet database. So you meant I should delete the for and lastrow statement? And how do I update the r3 range?

Comment: No don't touch the set r3 above, but set it again in the for loop.

Comment: Please check my latest edit, I am not quite sure this is right, the result is not what I expected, it only return value in F2.

Comment: Ok first, the first 'set r3', change the range from F2 to F2:T2, second delete the for/next loop. Thirdly, replace the 'if rw1 <>0 then' by 'do while rw1 <>0', and replace the 'end if' by 'loop'

Comment: Please check update, I don't think the loop is working, no it only copies data from Column A in Database to F2:T2 in Reports. And in this case what is the point of defining last row.

Comment: Ok I'll have to take a look at it on the PC later, and the lastrow is not needed anymore

Comment: Thank you so much! I think the problem might be the set r3 in the loop sentence,

Comment: Sorry I won't make it today anymore, but what you can try is declare one more range variable (eg tmpRng) and  ˋset tmprng = r1.find ...` , next you change `rw1 = tmprng.row`, and the line before `loop` you change to `tmprng = r1.findnext(tmprng)`. After that you insert the line `if not tmprng is nothing then rw1 = tmprng.row`

Comment: Ok, i'll try that and let you know. Thank you still! if you got anytime to have a look of the code, I will totally appreciate that!

Comment: it is still not working after I edited the code as you said. If you got time, please take a look at it on PC please. Now the result is just values that from A1 in sheet database copied to F:T range in sheet reports, and the loop won't stop resulting more than 10000 observation. I have to manually stop it.

Comment: Actually, there's one little thing that I forgot to mention in my question, which is how to erase the previous content before print out the contents of  other macros. I have several macros of this format, only cell changes in the searchValue sentence. I need to bounce among them, since the contents have different numbers of row, which could cause a problem. I have tried to insert clearcontents statement in the front of this code and in between the do.loop, and it just cleared everything altogether, is there any simple code that could be embedded here to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by previous content? what area exactly do you want to clear?

Comment: Sorry, don't mind me. It is probably because my computer was having a strike, it works now, thank you!!! I really appreciate your help!